# Focus state remains after DOM element is updated

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bulma

I'm using [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) + [Bulma](https://bulma.io/).

A button click event is used to update the DOM. However, after the DOM has been updated, the focus state is still applied to the button.

I want the updated button not to have the focus state.

What is the best way to deal with this? Is there a more idiomatic Vue.js way of dealing with this common scenario?

Reduced example below:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: [{
      text: "This is the first text"
    }, {
      text: "This is the second text"
    }, {
      text: "This is the third text"
    }],

    index: 0,
  },

  methods: {
    nextText: function() {
      if (this.index < this.options.length - 1) {
        this.index++;
      } else {
        this.index = 0;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="nextText()" class="button is-primary is-outlined">{{ options[index].text }}</button>
</div>
```

[image: animated GIF showing the issue]

Comment: But you _are_ still hovering the element, are you not? I doubt that you managed to move your mouse cursor away from the element, in the fraction of milliseconds it took to change the button text ...

Comment: @CBroe run the code snippet. Even with the mouse off the button, its remains in its hover state.

Comment: That's not the _hover_ state, but _focus_ - which the button receives because you are clicking on it.

Comment: @CBroe any idea how to deal with this on mobile? My answer below fixes on desktop, but I'm still having the same issue on mobile

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by forcing Vue to re-render the button element.

This makes sense in my context, as I want the button to behave as a new button and not have any previous 'focus' applied to it.

This can be achieved by setting the :key attribute on the button.

```
 <button v-on:click="nextText()" :key="index" class="button is-primary is-outlined">{{ options[index].text }}</button>
```

Updated code below.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: [{
      text: "This is the first text"
    }, {
      text: "This is the second text"
    }, {
      text: "This is the third text"
    }],

    index: 0,
  },

  methods: {
    nextText: function() {
      if (this.index < this.options.length - 1) {
        this.index++;
      } else {
        this.index = 0;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="nextText()" :key="index" class="button is-primary is-outlined">{{ options[index].text }}</button>
</div>
```